# Why can't I post in my id frontend when passing it to backend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, backend

I'm having a problem wherein I want to post my items but it doesn't work ..Here is the code for frontend but I'll explain it first..so basically the process here is when I registered my account it will automatically add to my users and to my likers model in my mongoose. To be more specific.. I have this thing

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
      axios.get('http://localhost:7171/users/')
        .then(list => setlist(list.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        // console.log(list)

      axios.get('http://localhost:7171/likes')
        .then(listid => setlistid(listid.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

  },[])
```

This one will read the data that I created...and after that when I registered my item it will do something like this..

```
const Register = e => {

    axios.post('http://localhost:7171/users/register',e)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

}

//Something function submit here 
if (name.length >= 6 && key.length >= 6) {
          setCallError("Your Account has Registered")
          Register(Inputs)   
          console.log(listid[0]._id,listid[1]._id,listid[2]._id,listid[3]._id,listid[4]._id)

          axios.post(`http://localhost:7171/likes/item/${listid[0]._id}`,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error:' + err))

          // axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+listid[1]._id,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
          //   .then(res => console.log(res.data))
          //   .catch(err => console.log('Error:' + err))

          // axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+listid[2]._id,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
          //   .then(res => console.log(res.data))
          //   .catch(err => console.log('Error:' + err))

          // axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+listid[3]._id,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
          //   .then(res => console.log(res.data))
          //   .catch(err => console.log('Error:' + err))

          // axios.post('http://localhost:7171/likes/item/'+listid[4]._id,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
          //   .then(res => console.log(res.data))
          //   .catch(err => console.log('Error:' + err))

        }
```

Just don't mind the other codes function this is just how to show you will it process just focus on this thing

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:7171/likes/item/${listid[0]._id}`,{ people:{name:name,key:key }})
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error:' + err))
```

I just comment out first my other post so that you can identify what I am doing here..cause I just want to post my 5 items at the same item..but there is a problem here. When I will try to submit this it will give me this kind of error in my post `POST http://localhost:7171/likes/item/00000001a24dfc9b806e607f 400 (Bad Request)` I don't understand why it is wrong I just passed it in id.. By the way this is my backend first

This code tells that I wanna reupdate my certain id since I want to append a new item in its list
`people` whenever I will register a user.

```
router.route('/item/:id').post((req,res) => {

    const { likes, people } = req.body
    
    const id = req.params.id
    
    console.log(id)

    if (!id) return res.status(400).json({ message: "missing id" });

    Main.updateOne(
        { _id: (id) },
        {
            $set: {
                likes,
            },
            $addToSet: { people: { $each: people } },
        },
        )
        .then((likes) => res.json({ message: "New User Added" }))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error :" + err));


})
```

but what I mean about here is that I passed the right id that I read in the data but I don't understand when I am trying to post it in the id that reads the data.. as you see that `listid[0]._id` it means I want to pass my id that I created but i don't understand why it can't post the items...but when I am trying to create it in my postman like this. It is working very well..Do you guys have any idea?? Or notice wrong at my codes I don't see it anywhere.
[image]

**EDITED**
Here is the console.log(listid)
[image]

And here is for the backend part
[image]

Comment: Can you `console.log(listid)` right before your `listid[0]._id` axios request and share a screenshot of what `listid` is?

Comment: ok wait sir imma do it

Comment: Already edited sir :D

Comment: Help me sir T_T im struggling with this annoying post.. I did it right but I don't find any wrong here.

Comment: There are two statements that can throw 400 error from your code. Which one is it in this case? If `console.log(id)` if working fine then can you `console.log(err)` on backend for the 2nd one and share screenshot of that ?

Comment: Do you mean my `Main.updateOne( )` function? which will be the `catch`?

Comment: Yes, if the error is because of that then that might provide some more information

Comment: Here you go sir I'm done.

Comment: `people` apparently is not an array. Have you tried logging `req.body.people` on backend? If that doesn't show up, you do have body parser right ?

Comment: Oh sir in my 4th code snippet you can see it `const { likes, people } = req.body`

Comment: But does `console.log(people)` log the array that you are passing from Postman or no?

Comment: Oh sir I already got it.. I just have to do something like this in my frontend 

`axios.post(`http://localhost:7171/likes/item/${listid[0]._id}`,{ people:[{key:key,name:name}]})`
I didn't notice i need an array it..Thanks for the hint sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says `$each` takes an array as argument but `people` doesn't seem to be defined when making request from client. You should add people to your Axios request body just like in Postman. Alternatively, you can pass an empty array if people is undefined:

```
Main.updateOne({
    _id: (id)
  }, {
    $set: {
      likes,
    },
    $addToSet: {
      people: {
        $each: people || [] // empty array if people is undefined
      }
    },
  }, )
  .then((likes) => res.json({
    message: "New User Added"
  }))
```